# Read data from specific memory address / reference to object

Tags: python, memory, reference

How can I read (and put into new variable) data stored at specific memory address?

For instance I know that:

```
  <nfqueue.queue; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'queue *' at 0xabd2b00> >
```

And I want to have data stored at 0xabd2b00 in new variable so that I can work and use all functionalities of the object. Let's assume that I don't have access to the original variable that created this object.

UPDATE:
Above question has been answered so I update my question.
Let's assume I have two python files: file1.py and file2.py

File1.py:

```
.... rest of the code ....
class new_thread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, obj):
       self.obj = obj
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        str = 'python file2.py'
        args = shlex.split(str3)
        tmp = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=open('/dev/null','w'), stderr=open('/dev/null', 'w'))
.... rest of the code ....
```

At some point thread new_thread is called.

File2.py:

```
kolejka = nfqueue.queue()
```

Here the queue is created, binded and opened. Then endless loop for listening is executed. The only way to end it is to unbind and close kolejka, but I want file1.py to do that as it is a "master" programme. How can I retrieve initialized kolejka from file to close queue properly after new_thread is done?

When I try:

```
from file2 import kolejka
```

The script executes all procedure of creating queue from the beginning (it hasn't been written as a function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't - there is no way to read data from a specific address. If you don't have (or can't retrieve) a reference to the object you're interested in, you're out of luck.

Besides, even if you **could** read data from a given address, that wouldn't help, since there would be no way for you to know which address to read from unless you have a reference to the original object. And then you wouldn't need to read raw data from memory in the first place.

---

### Update - How to terminate the child process cleanly

There are ways to share memory between processes in Python (for example the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module). However, this seems a bit overkill for your problem. Since you're starting the `file2` process from within `new_thread`, the easiest solution is probably to use the [signal](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) module to let `new_thread` tell the `file2` process to exit when the main program exits.

This allows `file2.py` to perform any cleanup needed before shutting down, and it's also a clean solution since `file1.py` doesn't need to know the details about how to shut down `file2.py`, making your code more modular and easier to maintain.

#### file1.py

```
def run(self):
    ...
    child_process = subprocess.Popen(args, ...)
    ...
    # time to quit - tell file2 to terminate
    child_process.terminate()
```

#### file2.py

```
import signal
import sys
...
kolejka = nfqueue.queue()
...
def sigterm_handler(signum, frame):
    # close kolejka and do any other cleanup needed, then do:
    sys.exit()

# Make sure sigterm_handler() is run when file1.py tells us
# to quit using child_process.terminate()
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)
```

Comment: So what is the best way to get reference of the variable from another (running) python script? Does 'from script2 import variable' does the trick? What if the desired variable is located in function SomeFunc()?

Comment: It's hard to give a good answer without more information about your problem. Could you update your question with some code samples illustrating your problem? A short example showing where the variable is defined and where you need to use it would be great.

Comment: Done. I hope that my description will help to imagine the issue I struggle with.

Comment: Thanks, now it's much more clear what you're trying to accomplish. I've updated my answer with a suggestion on how to terminate both processes cleanly - hope this helps!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for remainding me that signals do exist :)